# byte object length issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I’m in a bit of a bind due to version restrictions.
I have to encrypt some data in alteryx app which uses python 3 and decrypt that data in another place(Unix box) that has python 2

As an example of what I’m doing. This is code and output in python 3

Package - pycryptodome

```
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
a=get_random_bytes(16)
b=get_random_bytes(16)
k=bytes(a ^ b for a,b in zip(a, b))
print(len(a))
print(len(b))
print(len(k))
```

This results in length 16, 16, 16

But the same thing when run in python 2 gives me the length of k as 46, which is causing an issue. How do I fix this? I’m not python savvy.

Comment: Just typed this code on my phone since I cannot login to this site on my work laptop

Comment: See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals) from the docs. In python 2, `bytes` is just an alias for `str`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve the same result in both Python 3 and Python 2:

```
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

def get_random_bytes_py2(size):
    return bytearray(get_random_bytes(size))

a = get_random_bytes(16)
b = get_random_bytes(16)

# Convert a and b to bytearrays in Python 2
a = get_random_bytes_py2(16)
b = get_random_bytes_py2(16)

# Perform XOR operation
k = bytearray(a[i] ^ b[i] for i in range(16))

print(len(a))
print(len(b))
print(len(k))
```

This code should produce the same result in both Python 3 and Python 2, with len(a), len(b), and len(k) all being 16.